# Using map to pass four elements into one component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using map to iterate over an array in React. I want to pass four props into the same component (two player names and two player ids). These are generated from an array of player names. Each MatchCard needs two players. At present I can only pass duplicated information in. What's the best way to do this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MatchCard from "../MatchCard";
import Shuffler from "../Shuffler";

class TournamentGrid extends Component {
  render(playerNames) {
    let players = this.props.playerNames;
    return (
      <div className="inline-block flex justify-center">
        <div className="ml-2 mr-2">
          {players.map((player, index) => (
            <>
              <MatchCard
                key1={index}
                key2={index}
                player1={player}
                player2={player}
              />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TournamentGrid;
```

Comment: what other id and player name are you trying to pass as props into the MatchCard component?

Comment: The array contains a list of player names. I want to pass in 2 player names into each MatchCard - so there are player1, player2, key1 and key2 props

Comment: Iterating over an array will only give you a single element. If you want to pass two player objects as props then you need to mention which two players you want to pass using a custom logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to render two match participants into one component I'd suggest you to store the data in a different manner. How can you retrieve match data from an array? Are you populating it with tuples of players? In this case I think `Array.map()` is the wrong method, as it cycles through the whole thing, and that's not what you need.
If you can't update your data model this would be a workaround...

```js
import React from 'react';
import MatchCard from '../MatchCard';

class TournamentGrid extends React.Component {
  renderMatches() {
    const players = this.props.playerNames;

    return players.forEach((player, index) => {
      if (index % 2)
        return (
          <MatchCard
            key1={index}
            key2={index + 1}
            player1={player}
            player2={players[index + 1]}
          />
        );

      return null;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="inline-block flex justify-center">
        <div className="ml-2 mr-2">{this.renderMatches()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was planning on keeping the data structure as an array and removing losers from the array as the brackets play out. You make a good point about changing the data structure, so I think I will go down this route. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to pass in 2 elements at a time to each MatchCard, in which case the below solution should be sufficient:

```
players.forEach((player, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 1) {
        return null
    }
    
    return <>
          <MatchCard
            key1={index}
            key2={index + 1}
            player1={players[index]}
            player2={players[index + 1]}
          />
    </>
})
```